# Error: "AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio"

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pyaudio

I am trying to install the PyAudio package, as described in this link: https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/#working-with-microphones.

I went to this site to install PyAudio: [https://lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). I installed PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

This was necessary, according to this documentation: https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/1.2.3

Then, to install PyAudio, I used the command "pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl", which installed the module successfully.

The issue is that, when I try running this line of code in PyCharm:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

The pip command installed a pyaudio.py file, and I put that into the same folder as the SpeechRecognition folder. I also tried putting pyaudio.py into the same folder as the project I'm working on.

**I am using Python 3.8 in PyCharm on Windows 10. What can I do to fix this problem?**

Edit 1: I don't know if this will be useful, but when I try only running

```
import pyaudio
```

then this error pops up:

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
```

...

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_portaudio'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

pycharm create new env so you have to install py audio in pycharm env so to do that

- first open pycharm and click ctrl+alt+s it will open settings tab
- then click project:your project name then click on projecy interpreter
- teen press plus butoon to add a packege
- search for pyaudio and install it
- [image: see this image]

Comment: The problem is that when I try following your steps, I get this error: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1. According to https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/1.2.3/, the official PyAudio build is broken for Windows, at least for Python 3.8, which is the version I'm using.

Comment: ok then check it in idle by typing `import pyaudio`

Comment: I think it works in Idle, but I'm wondering if you know how to get it to work in PyCharm. Basically, is there some way to install packages in PyCharm without using the default method like you showed above?

Comment: then go to your pycharm env folder in cmd with command cd and do the same thing how you install locally

Comment: i mean runthis command in that env activated `pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`

Comment: to activate pycharm venv just runthe this command `C:\Users\user_name\PycharmProjects\project_name\venv\Scripts\activate`

Comment: Can you add more detail about what you mean by "that env activated?"